# History js statechange not work on IE msie

Tags: internet-explorer, bind, adapter, history.js

my script noot work on IE, specially statechange
My code:

```
var History = window.History;
var State = History.getState();
var $log = $('#log');

console.log(State.url);

History.Adapter.bind(window,'statechange',function(){ 
          List_url(State.url, State.url); 

 });


 History.pushState({state:1,rand:Math.random()}, parametro, parametro);
```

If I use IE browser the function is block because do not work the History.Adapter.bind statechange

You know the solution?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Which version of IE? The HTML5 History API wasn't added until IE10.